# WR1043ND + WRT54G for extending Wifi range. How can I set them up to seamless signal switch?

Tags: router, wrt54g, signal-strength, wireless-extender

I have a tp-link wr1043nd connected to my modem. This router has wifi but the signal is not strong enough for some parts of the house. I wanted to use my old wrt54g to extend the signal.

Ive tried a few things but what Im not able to do is to setup a single SSID for the whole network, so the devices would change from router to router seamlessly whenever they find a stronger signal.

Ive tried to configure them as WDS but it didnt work. Apparently they are way too different for that.

Is there any way to achieve what I want? At the moment I have the wrt54g set to repeater bridge, and on a different SSID cause if I leave the same SSID, I got tons of disconnections.

Answer (score 1):

Seamless roaming is only possible using either WDS or by connecting the two access points with a wired Ethernet connection. There's no reason WDS shouldn't work -- it's a standard.

Wire them to each other LAN port to LAN port if at all possible. This not only solves the compatibility problems but allows the two devices to operate on different channels and removes the bandwidth halving that occurs due to signals being re-broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

First one is Router mode and set the second router as repeater mode and add the router in repeater mode router it works fine and wifi is exented

Comment: He wants seamless roaming. That's not possible in repeater mode.